# Inserting multiple files to mysql on command line

Tags: linux, command-line, mysql

I am using Ubuntu and MySQL.

I have a list of many `.sql` files, like `1.sql`, `2.sql`, `3.sql` ... `100000.sql`

I need to insert them into the database.

```
    mysql mydb < *.sql
```

Gives me:

```
    -bash: *.sql: ambiguous redirect
```

Any idea how can I do it from command line? (I know I can write a Python script to do it with no problem, but I want to do it from the command line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no MySQL available but I believe `cat *.sql | mysql mydb` should work.

Answer (score 2):

If Nifle's answer doesn't work, then try:

```
for f in *.sql
do
    mysql mydb < "$f"
done
```